# make response Url Valid Ios

Tags: ios, url

I am developing ios application where I am waiting for response which should be uploaded image Url. I am converting NSData to NSString this way.

```
NSString* resultInString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

when I log resultInString, I get __NSCFString * @"\"http:\/\/em.avatars.s3.amazonaws.com\/avatarsd765c404-887c-4c0e-a08b-f7066ec9befe.png\"" 0x17777080

I have no idea how to validate this url to set UIImageview in my application. please give me a hint.

Comment: What's the problem with it? It's a url. What's to validate?

Answer (score -1):

before say something about solution i think  your getting url from NSData is incorrect.
The response seems to be JSON-encoded. So simply decode the response string using a JSON library (SBJson, JsonKit etc.) 
or you can user correct encode for your NSData.
after all you can create a NSUrl from your string & if it's exist so it's valid.

i write a sample code for you
you should remove some charectar from your url by this way or like this

```
[urlString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and for validation

```
   NSUrl * url  =  [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];


    if(url){ //valid url
```

}